# Handle exception while assigning attributes and add error on one to many relation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, exception, rails-activerecord, carrierwave

We have a model with an order that can have multiple cards. Each card is associated with a picture. Sometimes an exception happens when uploading the picture. The upload is mounted with `carrierwave`. How and where can I catch this exception and add an error to the corresponding card (preferably in the card.rb class)?

I guess I could generalize the question to: how does one handle exceptions while assigning attributes on a one to many relationship and add errors to the corresponding fields?

The order class looks like this (simplified):

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cards, class_name: 'Card'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards, allow_destroy: true

end
```

The card class looks like this (simplified):

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  crop_uploaded  :picture

end
```

Controller code:

```
class OrderController < ApplicationController

  def submit
      order.assign_attributes(order_params)

      if order.valid?
        ...
      else
        render :show
      end
  end   

  protected

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(
      card_attributes: [:picture_crop_x, :picture_crop_y, :picture_crop_w, :picture_crop_h, :picture, :_destroy]
  end

end
```

Comment: are you doing accepts_nested?

Comment: @Austio Yes, we do, I have added it to the code above.

Comment: @MichielBorkent Does it [help](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-add) to answer your question about the addition of error to a field ?

Comment: Well, so what is the issue ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit The issue is that the exception happens in `order.assign_attributes(order_params`, but I don't know how to plug in to that in order to add the error to card in which the exception was caused.

Comment: Actually the error should raise when you are calling `order.valid?` ,, not before that.. Right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87614/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-michiel-borkent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this as follows:

1) Added an attribute to the card model:

```
attr_accessor :crop_failed
```

2) Added a validation method:

```
validate  :crop_success?

def crop_success?
  errors.add(:picture, 'Image cannot be processed.') if crop_failed == true
end
```

3) In the Uploader class we catched the exception and set the attribute :crop_failed to true.

```
def crop
  model.crop_failed = nil
  ...
rescue Exception => e
  model.crop_failed = true
end
```